# Node.js route error when clicking buttons in .ejs file

Tags: node.js, ejs

I have an edit and delete button in a .ejs file, and problem is that when i click the delete button I am redirected to the edit view file instead of delete code which will delete the data from the database, a second problem is when I try to edit something in the edit view page it doesn't update the database, it just reloads my edit view page. Please find the gist of code below.

https://gist.github.com/brianpolanco8/1cf586ef897506f0098d5dc3d53a1767

Comment: Just to assist, put some `console.log(err)` after your `if(err)`
Something like `if(err){ console.log(err); DOSOMETHING}`
Watch what's your problem by this way and will be more simple to fixed it